# JavaScript Server Build Bundle

Tags: javascript, angular, express, webpack, server-side-rendering

It seems that with the modern JavaScript approach resumability, lazy load, on demand etc. All of those things lead to a lot of chunk files, when we build the application.

Once we build the application for the browser with optimizations minification etc.
And once for the server for SSR.

The question is about those server build chunks and are they harm the server rendering and response time. My thoughts are if we lazy load them on the server as well.

Don't we have a lot of read/execute time to import them in the server application?

I am not with big experience don't even know how to test this theory. I expect that with some webpack config to tell when build the server to ignore the import() in code and bundle all files into one, but this way don't we gonna have a big startup time because the main file is gonna be big?

Comment: It's a trade-off. And it can be configured to use fewer chunks if that's what you want.

Comment: I'd like to know am I right about the possible performance issue, because in my head this is just a theory may be webpack has some improvements and those imports came with no cost.

Comment: No. There's definitely a cost. Typically, the trade-off is between the size of entry point bundles, smaller meaning faster initial loading, and round trips to the server. However, if you end up with a bunch of small chunks that always load together, then there's a downside. Webpack has built-in configuration and plugins that allow you to control this behavior. Personally, I would stick with the default behavior until you run into a performance problem.